# Apache Tomcat не видит класс Java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Всем доброго времени суток! Разрабатываю сервлет (Eclipse Indigo, Apache Tomcat, J2EE), опыта очень мало. В сервлете надо задействовать метод Java-класса, который находится на той же машине, что и сам Tomcat. Какие есть способы заставить сервлет дополнительный класс ? Листинг сервлета:

```
public class PrepayServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public PrepayServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String host = "xxx";
    String port = "xxx";
    String login = "xxx";
    String password = "xxx";   
    boolean isRMIHttp = true;


   LogonInfo log = Session.createSession(host, port, login, getEncryptedPassword(password, false, 0),false);

   PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
   pw.print(Session.getServerPurpose());

   stations.service.StationsIface stationServer;
   stationServer = (stations.service.StationsIface) Session.getService("gbas.tvk.nsi.stations.service.StationsServer");
```

Проблема с видимостью stations.service.StationsIface, он находится вне класса сервлета в другом классе. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: можно увидеть структуру проекта  и листинг "невидимого" класса? Импорты прописывали в сервлете?

Comment: а так не пробовали `gbas.tvk.nsi.stations.service.StationsServer stationServer`???

Comment: как вы собираете проект? как разворачиваете на сервер?

Comment: Если класс из библиотеки, т.е. из файла jar, то этот jar должен быть либо размещён в папке WEB-INF/lib вашего веб-приложения, либо в папке общих библиотек сервера. Если это класс непосредственно веб-приложения, то обычно размещается в папке WEb-INF/classes. Считаю в любом случае следует для начала узнать как пакуются приложения java того или иного вида. Что в них включается и по каким местам располагается. Далее дело техники.

Comment: Так пробовал, не подходит все равно gbas.tvk.nsi.stations.service.StationsServer stationServer. Сложность  в том, что подключаемый класс не является частью фактически веб-приложения, а другого java-приложения и размещен вне структуры текущего веб-проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Я не могу добавить комментарий, потому что у меня не хватает репутации :)
Поэтому отвечаю отдельным ответом:
Вот за эту фразу нужно зацепиться:

> Сложность в том, что подключаемый класс не является частью фактически
>   веб-приложения, а другого java-приложения и размещен вне структуры
>   текущего веб-проекта

Если подключаемый класс лежит в отдельном проекте, то внимание:
1. Этот отдельный проект для Вашего приложения с сервлетом должен стать внешней библиотекой.
2. Для этого отдельный проект нужно скомпилировать в JAR-файл.
3. А полученный на шаге-2 JAR-файл нужно положить в проект с Вашим сервлетом - внимание - **в папку WEB-INF\lib**

**Второй способ** - если Вы собираете приложение Maven-ом, то проект с внешним классом - должен стать Maven-модулем и подключаться к проекту с сервлетом, как Maven-dependency.

**Третий способ** - Любая IDE умеет подключить один проект к другому.
Но, во-первых, Вы должны сказать, какую IDE используете.
А, Во-вторых, это самый не приемлемый, можно сказать, - школьный способ.

Если где наврал, пожалуйчта, уточняйте.

Comment: Всем спасибо, кто помогал, никак не мог сообразить простую вещь - создать артефакт из другого проекта и подключить его к другому проекту, теперь все хорошо.